# Slide down like music app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm wondering how would you make a slide down view (that you can slide up at any time) like the new music app in ios 8.4. Like getting it to actually react to finger position not just flat animation.

Comment: You can add an `UIView` on `window` and use `UIPanGestureRecogniser` to move up and down.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using [LNPopOver](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController). It works exactly like apple music by swizzling some methods.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the whole view first, configure it in such way that only top portion of the song being played is visible at the bottom of list of songs screen.

And add the pan gesture on the song screen and handle the transition in the gesture handler according to you suitability.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a view whose height is equal to the screen height with button at the top, equal to the song that is in presently played in music app.

set the constraint in such a way that it shows only the button, on button press animate the constraint to 0

Initially hide the down arrow once, the view is full stretch show down arrow and hide original button

config a BOOL to check the state of the view expand or contract, or do it via button.selected state